# PHP: trying to put href HTML attribute into a `echo`

Tags: php, echo, href

I can't seem to get a URL into `echo`. I want to make a link to open Google Maps:

[image]

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cev")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $name = $row['sitecode'];
  $lat = $row['latitude'];
  $lon = $row['longitude'];
  $type = $row['sitetype']; 
  $city = $row['city']; 
  $id = $row['id'];

  echo("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><a href="editcev.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">View</a><br><br/>$type<br/>$city');\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fix the quotes:

```
 echo "addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><a href=\"editcev.php?id={$row['id']}\">View</a><br><br/>$type<br/>$city');\n";
```

### Alternative ways

[**Here document**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
echo <<<EOS
addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b><a href="editcev.php?id={$row['id']}">View</a><br><br/>$type<br/>$city');

EOS;
```

**Concatenation**

```
echo "addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b>" .
  "<a href=\"editcev.php?id={$row['id']}\">View</a>" .
  "<br><br/>$type<br/>$city)";
```

**Using `addshashes`**

The `addMarker` looks like a JavaScript function. You might pre-process the HTML string by means of [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php):

```
$html = <<<EOS
<b>$name</b><a href="editcev.php?id={$row['id']}">View</a><br><br/>$type<br/>$city
EOS;
$html = addslashes($html);

echo "addMarker($lat, $lon, '$html');\n";
```

### Recommendations

I recommend using an editor with support of syntax highlighting.

Read about [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Especially the matter of escaping.

Finally, I wouldn't recommend writing *any* HTML/JavaScript within a PHP code. Use template engines such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) instead.

Comment: for 2 answers, you could use heredocs/newdocs for this.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use method inside the echo statement. If you want to use methods, variables or some php stuffs you should not use quotes at most case unless it is an eval featured object or method.

Try like this

```
echo addmarker($lat, $lon, 
               '<b>'.$name.'</b> <a href="'.editcev.php?id=.' '.$row['id'].
               ".'>View</a><br><br/>'
               .$type.
               '<br/>'
               .$city.');'."\n");
```

I don't know your exact situation but i think this works

Answer (score -1):

```
  echo("addMarker(".$lat.",".$lon.",<b>".$name."</b><a href=ditcev.php?id=" . $row['id'] . ">View</a><br><br/>".$type."<br/>".$city.");\n");
```